# Avoiding memory inefficiency when overring toString() of a common POJO using StringBuilder

Tags: java, out-of-memory, immutability

I'm developing a project that all my POJOs must have they `toString()` inherited from `Object class` overridden.

Consider the immutable class below:

```
public final class SomeActivity {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final String description;
    private final DateTime startDate;
    private final DateTime endDate;
    private final String note;

    // Constructors and getters

    // My future implementation of toString
}
```

My objective when overriding `toString()` is to achieve and output similar of the output below (using test values of all `SomeActivity` class fields):

`[Id: 1, Name: Read a book, Description: Trying to discover how to build a plane, StartDate: 17/10/2013, EndDate: 15/11/2013, Note: I really need this]`

So, I have two solutions in mind:

**1 - Concatenate Strings**

As far I know, `String` is a immutable class. (refer to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)), so, if I implement a method to receive such output, I may have many objects being created because of my concatenations:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String s = "[Id: " + id + 
            ", Name: " + name + 
            ", Description: " + description + 
            ", StartDate: " + startDate + 
            ", EndDate: " + endDate + 
            ", Note: " + note + 
            "]";
}
```

**2 - Using StringBuilder**

With `StringBuilder` approach, in theory, I would have less objects being instantiated instead of the "concatenation approach". But notice `new StringBuilder` and `toString()` calls of the code below:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("[Id: ").append(id)
                .append(", Name: ").append(name)
                .append(", Description: ").append(description)
                .append(", StartDate: ").append(startDate)
                .append(", EndDate: ").append(endDate)
                .append(", Note: ").append(note)
                .append("]");

        return builder.toString();
}
```

This second alternative, is really the **best possible**? Or is there another approach that I should adopt? Consider those `toString` methods being called from a `loop` statement.

Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with memory tests, so if is possible to write tests for that, I'll be very glad to know about that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get where you think the memory could leak in your code. Can you precise this point ? In any way your code looks fine.

Comment: Memory leaks are very difficult to create in java, which one do you think is leaking? And how?

Comment: I believe, Bruno is not afraid of "memory leak", but rather "inefficiency in terms of memory".

Comment: In case this is a definition problem; a memory leak is (in basic terms) when an object is held onto in memory even though it is no longer visible in the program; a sort of ghost object. Simply using a huge amount of memory is not a memory leak. See; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak

Comment: You guys are right, I've edited the title for better definition of the problem.

Comment: As I commented on Jon's anwser, it's good to know that I misunderstood how the concatenations of code are handled by Java, the first approach doesn't look so dangerous now, but, I will adopt the second one, as you guys suggested.
Also, even I wrote `memory leaks` instead of the correct title `inneficient`, it's good to know that both doesn't exists in my code.
I really appreciate your comments. Thanks.

Comment: @DevBlanked: What makes you think the 2nd approach is best practice? Why do you want to manually do what the compiler will do automatically for you?

Comment: @JonSkeet i find the 2nd way easier to maintain and read. If your class has a lot of properties, having all of them concatenated using + can be a bit awkward. When it comes to adding new properties or deleting existing properties of the class 2nd approach is more easier to work with in my view

Comment: @DevBlanked: Right, it's fine to say that you prefer one version instead of another - but claiming it's explicitly "best practice" suggests there's a significant concrete difference between the two. (I'd also point out that if you reformat the code to have one label/field per line, it's actually not significantly more awkward - in fact it can be easier to read without all the `append` fluff.)

Comment: @JonSkeet in the 1st approach if you don't have it as a single line the compiler wouldn't be able to optimize it. therefore i think best option is to go with the 2nd approach

Comment: @DevBlanked: No, there's a difference between a single *statement* and a single *line*. You can split the single statement over several lines with no problem.

Comment: @DevBlanked For example your current example of concatenation is 3 lines but one statement, it could be 7 lines without changing the actual code

Comment: Be shure to take  a look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html

Comment: @DevBlanked: See my edited answer for a suggested format for the concatenation approach.

Comment: @JonSkeet I haven't seen you edit while doing my own edit to format the concatenation approach, I'm sorry. I hope I did it the way you want, but feel free to edit again to make it the way you like.

Comment: @BrunoGasparotto: Well I was editing my answer rather than the question :) Notice that I've moved the "[" out of the first field though, making it slightly easier to add a new first field. (You'd still need to add a comma, admittedly.)

Comment: If all the classes are immutable like your example *and* you've profiled to discover that calling `toString` in a loop is affecting performance, I recommend eagerly calculating the result of `toString` in the constructor and storing it in a private field. The result can then be returned immediately by `toString`. However, the memory taken up by that `String` will have the same lifetime as the object, this may not be desired. A common rule of thumb is to write the most readable code, then optimise *iff* there's a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As far I know, String is a immutable class. (refer to the javadoc), so, if I implement a method to receive such output, I may have many objects being created because of my concatenations:

Nope. As you're performing all the concatenation in a single large expression, the compiler will pretty much just create the `StringBuilder`-equivalent code for you.

> But notice new StringBuilder and toString() calls of the code below:

Um, yes - and? It would be unusual to create a `toString` method which used various different field values but *didn't* create a string.

There's no memory leak here. Yes, you'll create a `StringBuilder` and `String`, but they'll be garbage collected appropriately.

Feel free to use either of these forms - or `String.format`, perhaps - whatever you find simplest to read. If you use the first form, I'd reformat it to have one description and one field value per line:

```
return "["
    + "Id: " + id 
    + ", Name: " + name 
    + ", Description: " + description
    + ", StartDate: " + startDate 
    + ", EndDate: " + endDate 
    + ", Note: " + note
    + "]";
```

At this point it looks more like the second form, in terms of readability and ease of adding/removing fields.

Comment: Your first quote made me surprised, I was really believing that a new String would be createad for each element of the expression.
Besides that, it's good to know that there is no memory leak AND no inneficient use of memory, I recently read about it in Effective Java (Joshua Bloch) and got a little afraid of it.
I appreciate your awnser Jon.

Comment: @BrunoGasparotto New strings would be created if you used seperate lines for each and kept going `string=string+"newInfo";` `string=string+"newInfo2";` etc

Comment: @RichardTingle: It's important to note that it's not "separate lines" - it's "separate statements" which is important here. You can spread the single statement over multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

[ToStringBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) from apache commons has a very clean way to generate toString implementation.

```
   public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    boolean smoker;
   } 


   public String toString() {
     return new ToStringBuilder(this).
       append("name", name).
       append("age", age).
       append("smoker", smoker).
       toString();
   }
 }
```

This will produce a toString of the format:

> Person@7f54[name=Stephen,age=29,smoker=false]